# Specifying linked sql server in web.config

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string, linked-server

How do you set a linked server in `MVC3 Web.Config`?

We have a linked server that has a stored procedure `SP_PROC` that we need to run.  However, both the main `SQL` server `TESTSERVER1` and the linked server is set up in a test environment `TESTSERVER2`, so the name/ip will change once the application goes live.  Because of this I don't want to specify anything more than the `SP` name in the code.

I've tried specifying the linked server in the initial catalog field of the connection string, but that's throwing errors - so I assume I'm barking up the wrong tree..

Example connection string:

```
<add name="connectionName" connectionString="data source=TESTSERVER1;Initial Catalog=TESTSERVER2;user id.../>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linked Server is configured on the server, not the connection.  You connect to the main server and your query will reference the linked server by name in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM TESTSERVER2.database.dbo.tablename
```

I would recommend not using the actual server name for the linked server name, but abstracting it so your queries can port from one sever to the next.